# How to resolve unhandled runtime error while using next router

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-router

I am facing the below error while using `useRouter` from `next/router`.

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'getBoundingClientRect' of null`

```js
import React from 'react'
import Link from 'next/link'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

function ActiveLink({ children, href, activeClassName }) {
  const { asPath } = useRouter()
  console.log(asPath)

  return (
    <Link href={href} />
  )
}

export default ActiveLink
```

Comment: The code you posted has no reference to `getBoundingClientRect` and doesn't provide enough information about the error. Could you provide the code that's actually triggering the issue?

Comment: When I have added routing by using `Link`, this issue will be there. But if I am implementing the routing using <a href=""></a> then this issue will not be there. Can you help me out how can I resolve this issue?